# jquery sliding divs

Tags: jquery

I need to slide a div with a content:  on link click, the div should slide out from right to left and when I click on second link, the visible div should slide out to the right and a div with a new content should slide out from right to left ... 
I use a history plugin as my pages should be loaded dinamicaly:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
        function load(num) {
            $('.leftside').load(num +".html",'',showNewContent());
        }

        $.history.init(function(url) {
            load(url == "" ? "page1" : url);
        });
        function showNewContent() {

            $(".leftside").css('left', function(){ 
                return $(".rightside").offset().left - $(".navigation").offset().left; })
             .animate({"left":"0px"}, {
                                        duration: 2000,
                                        specialEasing: {
                                          width: 'linear',
                                          height: 'swing'
                                        }
                                    });  
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('.leftside').fadeOut('normal');



        }
        $('.main-nav a').live('click', function(e) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
            $.history.load(url);
            return false;
        });

});
```

the html is something like this:

```
    <div class="leftside"></div> 
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#page1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the JS code works, but the divs doesn't slide as I described above ... do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: if anyone would be interested, I found a solution - very simple: $('.main-nav a').live('click', function(e) {
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
   if($('.leftside').is(':visible')){
    $('.leftside').stop().animate({left:"360px"}, {
          duration: 2000,
          specialEasing: {
            width: 'linear',
            height: 'swing'
          }
         }).animate({left:"0px"},1000);
    
   }
   else{
    $('.leftside').stop().animate({left:"0px"},1000);
   }
   $.history.load(url);
   return false;
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone would be interested, I found a solution - very simple:

```
$('.main-nav a').live('click', function (e) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
  if ($('.leftside').is(':visible')) {
    $('.leftside').stop().animate({
      left: '360px'
    }, {
      duration: 2000,
      specialEasing: {
        width: 'linear',
        height: 'swing'
      }
    }).animate({
      left: '0px'
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $('.leftside').stop().animate({
      left: '0px'
    }, 1000);
  }
  $.history.load(url);
  return false;
});
```